# Correlation between fundamental and market data

Tags: correlation, algorithmic-trading, mean-reversion, fundamentals, technicals

I got hold of a data set which contains fundamental data like analyst recommendations/revisions (consensus only) and I am trying to come up with an idea of how this could be used as a trading signal or as an addition to one of my other technical trading signals. From academic research that I have read, it sounds like there is very little informational content in such analyst recs as a stand-alone signal. My holding periods are anywhere between hours to 1-3 days, so I guess it might be better suited for buy and hold long-term strategies in the literature.

My initial idea would be to see if there is generally correlation between analyst publications and price movements (simple spearman/Pearson). The other idea that I got from some papers was, that the biggest correlations to prices happens $t-1$, due to insider information leakage. If I could see bigger moves happen before announcements, then one could leverage this as an entry point for a mean-reversion type strategy. If anyone has any idea how something like this could be done or any other idea about how to use the fundamental data that would be appreciated.

Comment: I have no experience using fundamental data (I use technical analysis), but my instinct here would be that you need a much larger holding timeframe to take into account the effects of fundamental analysis. Maybe you could start by looking at correlating analyst publications with the stock move over the next 3-12 months?

Comment: I agree in general, but my holding period would not fit into that framework. My initial guess would have been if anyone trades based on analyst recommendations I would assume to see some movement after the announcements.